# Error in RubyMine : no ruby interpreter configured for project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I installed RubyMine just now. It is the student free setup.

I am getting a warning/error: `no ruby interpreter configured for project`.

I opened it and tried to apply using both rbenv present, but warning/error doesn't goes off.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Which RubyMine version are you using? Does it happen to all the projects (even new ones in case you create them with the New Project wizard)?

Comment: Please read "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and their linked pages. We need to know where you researched and what you tried to fix this. Without that we would have to start at the beginning and explain every step possible, which means writing a tutorial, which is off-topic.

Comment: What Ruby version is declared in your gemfile? If that one is install and you see it in the `RubySDK and Gems` part of the preferences, try selecting the `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option form the File dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it just by deleting **.idea** directory from the my project file and everything started working with no no debugger issue.